# Git branches view with multiple projects

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We have 4 multi-module projects (Maven), each one in its own Git repository. There are interdependencies between the projects.

In order to have all our code available in a single IntelliJ window, I have imported all the projects as modules.

But this has had the following effect. The Changes > Log is the view where I can see all branches for my project. When I had 1 IntelliJ window per project, the branches I could see there were the branches of the project I had opened. Now that I have all the projects, I can see all the branches intermingled, and it makes it really difficult for me to understand what is going on.

[image]

In the screenshot above, the branches marked in blue belong to the same Git repository, and the branch marked in red belong to a different Git repository.

Although there are some filters, I can not see any filter by module (Git repository). It would seem obvious to me to only see branches group per Git repository. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you not use the structure filter?

Comment: In the structure filter you can select modules, not Git repositories. (1 Git repository can have several modules). And also, when those are selected, it gives you a git log -like history of the currently selected branch. Not an overview of all the branches.

Answer (score 8):

**Tips**

1. Select a repository from the `Paths` submenu.
2. `Cmd+click`(mac), `Alt+click`(win/linux) to select the specific one.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

OK, the solution for my question is the following:

VCS > Browse CVS repository > Show Git repository log.

Select the directory representing the Git repo you are interested in.

Comment: You can "pick it up" also from the global search - "Search everywhere window" , press twice Shift, and type/paste it "Show Git repository log"